# How to divide a global variable uniform over agents

Tags: netlogo

So I am working on a project that requires me to divide subsidy over two different types of turtles. I got 1 port and 25 industries (so, two breeds) and need to divide 15M EUR subsidy between the two breeds. So far, when I set the slider of subsidy on 50/50 (50% for port and 50% for industries), I get that 7.5 M for the port and 7.5 M for each industry but I want each industry to have 7.5M / 25 EUR. How can I solve this? See the code below:

```
to distribute-subsidies
  ask ports
 [ set subsidy-port (subsidy-port + 150000 * subsidy-to-port) / count ports
 ]
  ask industries
 [ set subsidy-industry (subsidy-industry + ((15000000 - 150000 * subsidy-to-port) / count industries ))
 ]
end
```

All help is welcome! Thanks in advance.

Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to be more clear with an example. Are you doing a 1-time transfer or every tick? I think it's clearer that you keep track of your subsidies to distribute in a variable. However, below I've provided an example to update the subsidies each tick and distribute the subsidies to both ports and industries, then within the ports and industries divide them amongst all the respective agents evenly.

```
to distribute-subsidies
      let subsidies 1500000
      ask ports
     [ set subsidy-port subsidy-port + ((subsidies * subsidy-to-port) / count ports)
     ]
      ask industries
     [ set subsidy-industry ((subsidies * ( 1 - subsidy-to-port)/ count industries)
     ]
    end
```

Comment: Hi! Sorry if I was unclear. I want the 15M to be distributed every tick, and adds to the previous value. So if there is nothing spend, with the slider being on 50/50, the port should get 7.5M in the first and 15M in the second and so forth. Got this now:

Comment: At this moment, the port works fine. However, the industries also get 7.5M each while that should be 7.5M / count industries. I don't see why it doesn't get that

Comment: Are you saying the solution I provided works? Can you provide some numerical examples?

Comment: Hi! Yes I got it working, one of the globals was already being defined in the setup as well. That caused the mix-up, just removed it from the setup line and used your code which worked. Thanks!